# In Moose subroutines, how does $meta get into @_?

Tags: perl, moose

[chromatic's recent blog](http://www.modernperlbooks.com/mt/2010/07/when-sugar-and-semantics-collide.html) got me curious about the Moose subroutine `has`. I was looking at the Moose source code and noticed that inside the `has` subroutine, there is a `$meta` variable unpacked from `@_`. Where does `$meta` come from? I've started wading through the various Moose and Class::MOP modules. In many subroutines, it seems that `$meta` is commonly found as the first argument in `@_`, even though it is not specifically passed to it as an argument.

Edit: Here is the original source code for the `has` subroutine:

```
sub has {
    my $meta = shift;
    my $name = shift;

    Moose->throw_error('Usage: has \'name\' => ( key => value, ... )')
        if @_ % 2 == 1;

    my %options = ( definition_context => Moose::Util::_caller_info(), @_ );
    my $attrs = ( ref($name) eq 'ARRAY' ) ? $name : [ ($name) ];
    $meta->add_attribute( $_, %options ) for @$attrs;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`molecules` comment in [ysth answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167259/in-moose-subroutines-how-does-meta-get-into/3168146#3168146):

> I'm not sure how the has subroutine gets converted to this closure, but this definitely shows the curried nature of the imported has

Here is (hopefully!) a simple example of how this could be achieved (however I suspect [`Moose`](http://moose.perl.org) does it in a much more complex and better way!)

**Meta.pm**

```
package Meta;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    bless { @_ }, $class;
}

sub has {
    my $meta = shift;
    print "Given => @_ \n";
    print "meta $_ => ", $meta->{$_}, "\n" for keys %$meta;
}

1;
```

**Import.pm**

```
package Import;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Meta;

# some arbitrary meta info!
our $Meta = Meta->new( a => 'A', b => 'B' );

sub import {
    my $caller = caller;

    # import 'has' into caller namespace
    no strict 'refs';
    *{$caller . '::has'} = sub { $Meta->has(@_) };
}

1;
```

**meta_has.pl**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Import;

has name => ( is => 'rw', isa => 'Int' );
```

Now if you run `meta_has.pl` you will get:

```
# Given => name is rw isa Int 
# meta a => A
# meta b => B
```

Hope that helps.

/I3az/

Answer (score 12):

The particular magic you are looking for is in [Moose::Exporter](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose::Exporter).  You get the `has` method via Moose.pm from this code:

```
Moose::Exporter->setup_import_methods(
    with_meta => [
        qw( extends with has before after around override augment )
    ],
    as_is => [
        qw( super inner ),
        \&Carp::confess,
        \&Scalar::Util::blessed,
    ],
);
```

Note the "with_meta" option for `setup_import_methods` -- it imports those methods into the caller's namespace in a manner which ensures that the first argument passed will be the metaclass object.

The various MooseX modules that extend Moose use Moose::Exporter to import new symbols into the caller's namespace.  You can read more about this process in the cookbook, starting at [Moose::Cookbook::Extending::Recipe1](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose::Cookbook::Extending::Recipe1).

Comment: +1 Thanks. I see that I need to spend a little time studying Moose::Exporter before I can really understand it. It's still not clear to me how `$meta` (or more accurately, the reference that `$meta` later refers to) gets into `@_`, but you've definitely pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: You may specifically want to look at the private method `_make_wrapped_sub_with_meta` inside `Moose::Exporter`. The return value from this is what is installed as `has` by Moose I believe.

Answer (score 6):

What's actually imported into into your package isn't the named has() subroutine but a closure that inserts the meta object.  You can see exactly how this happens with:

```
$ perl -we'use Data::Dump::Streamer; use Moose; Dump(\&has)'
my ($extra,$sub,@ex_args);
$extra = sub {
       package Moose::Exporter;
       use warnings;
       use strict 'refs';
       Class::MOP::class_of(shift @_);
     };
$sub = sub {
     package Moose;
     use warnings;
     use strict 'refs';
     my $meta = shift @_;
     my $name = shift @_;
     'Moose'->throw_error(q[Usage: has 'name' => ( key => value, ... )]) if @_ % 2 == 1;
     my(%options) = ('definition_context', Moose::Util::_caller_info(), @_);
     my $attrs = ref $name eq 'ARRAY' ? $name : [$name];
     $meta->add_attribute($_, %options) foreach (@$attrs);
   };
@ex_args = ( 'main' );
$CODE1 = sub {
       package Moose::Exporter;
       use warnings;
       use strict 'refs';
       my(@curry) = &$extra(@ex_args);
       return &$sub(@curry, @_);
     };
```

`$CODE1` is the closure itself; above are the variables referenced in it.

Comment: I changed it to `perl -we'package X; use Data::Dump::Streamer; use Moose; Dump(\&has)'` to get it to work on my Debian Lenny machine.

Comment: +1 Thanks. I'm not sure how the `has` subroutine gets converted to this closure, but this definitely shows the curried nature of the imported `has`.

Comment: For anyone that wants to see output that is a little less messy, try replacing `Dump(\&has)` in the one-liner with `Dump(\&after)`.